# Get out a value from promise Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, promise, ionic3

I need to get the userKey (auto-generated) for my future request:

```
addItemToCollection(userMail,item){

    let userKey;

    firebase.database().ref('user-list').orderByChild('email').equalTo(userMail)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

        //userkey is the value that i want
             userKey= child.key

        });
    }); 

    //Outside the promise i need userkey Value.
    this.collectionRef=this.db.list('user-list/'+userKey+'/collection/bouteille');

    return this.collectionRef.push(item); 

}
```

this.db can't be find in my promise that why im there today (im new to ionic 3 and firebase)

Comment: You can't synchronously get a value from a Promise. `await` can 'unpack' it in a way that *looks* synchronous, but that's just not how Promises work.

Comment: And I'm not trying to be offensive, we we're all learners once, but firebase, ionic, Promises, and typescript are all complex topics in their own right. You need to learn **JavaScript** (not TypeScript) and **HTML** (not webcomponents) and about the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code (and how Promises fit in to that). Learn about how Databases work. Then come back to ionic/TypeScript/Firebase/await. Otherwise the docs for these things will just confuse you: they'll assume you know things you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Make your function async, and put await before firebase call.